# Unable to auto scroll horizontally at end (right side) in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am using HTML style like `display: flex` so that I am able to display a panel at the right of the table. On clicking table row I am opening the right panel, at that time I want to auto scroll horizontally at end of the right side.

[image: Current Behavior Image]

[image: Expected Behavior]

I want this has to be done programmatically using  **Angular 6**.

Comment: Please provide an HTML and related ts code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scrollIntoView()` like:

```
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

by fetching element with `@ViewChild()`

[ScrollIntoView](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollintoview2)

[ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#example-1)

[ScrollIntoView Full options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: If I use like that, Its getting but it scrolls upto starting of that div not end

Comment: Use scrollIntoViewOptions | inline https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView  `ele.scrollIntoView({inline: "end"});`